# Getting all Permissions from APK, Android 6

Tags: android, permissions

With Android 6's dynamic permissions, is it possible to get all the permissions an APK requires from a compiled apk?

The problem is that in our project, we sometimes add third party libraries to our project, and sometimes they require more permissions than our app initially required. I would like to be able to detect such situations at the CI build stage.

Comment: "Dynamic permissions" does not change anything. They all still have `<uses-permission>` elements in the manifest. `aapt dump badging`, or reading in the merged manifest, will tell you what is requested.

Comment: @CommonsWare If you post this as a reply, I will be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Dynamic permissions" (a.k.a., runtime permissions) do not change anything. They all still have `<uses-permission>` elements in the manifest. `aapt dump permissions`, or reading in the merged manifest, will tell you what is requested by your current manifest.

This does not help with libraries that do not publish a manifest in their AARs that contain the `<uses-permission>` elements required by the library. Hopefully, the authors of such a library document what they are expecting and you are adding the `<uses-permission>` elements to your own manifest.